# How to optimize the locations and orientations of a collection of irregular 3D objects?

Tags: optimization, packing

I'm working on a project where I need to optimize both the locations and orientations of a collection of irregular 3D objects in a given simulation box.

To optimize the locations and orientations means the irregular 3D objects in the simulation box must not overlap, and the resulting packing configuration of the objects should be as relaxed as possible (imagine the objects are charged particles).

Is there an algorithm that can achieve this objective?

Comment: How do you measure how relaxed a particular configuration is?  Can you [edit] your question to specify an objective function that you want to minimize?

Comment: Did you find an algorithm that can solve this?